# Reading tag from XML and conversion failure in SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm having problem while reading XML tag from XML structure and later inserting it to database. Problem occurs with one tag: "`<UV>`". I have some files with the same structure and inside this tag I have one time values: "11" and in some of them there is value: "5.5". It is example here but I have number with 2 max decimal places. The problem is when SSIS package wants to read this tag when value is with decimal places. In database, this column is set to be Numeric(10,2) precision. In SSIS package I tried different data type columns but without appropriate success. Can onyone help me to read this  tag correctly? What should I change to make it working? I have following structure:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, I manually manipulated types in created XSD file changing existing type of variable/tag to correct one: type:"DECIMAL". This solved my problem here. This might help other not experienced developers and accelerate solving similar problems in the future. Regards, Darek.